# Angular service - GET returns undefined

Tags: angular, express, service

I'm trying to use an angular service to get users from a database. When doing a GET request IN the service, I can `console.log(res)` and get the response. However, when I try to grab the data from another component, it always comes up `undefined`. Please help.

users.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  users: any;

  getUsers() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users').subscribe(res => {
      this.users = res;
      return this.users;
    });
  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [ UsersService ]
})

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private usersService: UsersService
  ) {
    this.users = usersService.getUsers();
  }
```

And when I try to use it in app.component.html ...

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users"></div>
```

users comes up undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your service to centralize your users data, then consider this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
     this.getUsers()
          .subscribe(data => this.users = data);
  }

  users: any;

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users');

  }

}
```

then in your component:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public usersService: UsersService <------ changed to public to make it available to the template
  ) {
     // this.users = usersService.getUsers(); <------ commented out, as users is now centralized in the service
  }
```

and in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of usersService.users"></div>
```

By making these changes, your getUsers() method will only be called at the creation time of your UsersService (first time it appears in providers array) and your users data will be available to any component that injects UsersService.

Comment: This seemed like the cleanest way to do it, but it comes back undefined. Also, res.json() is redundant because the response is json (shown as outdated by a lot of other posts), and even when replacing res.json() with this.users = data, it still comes back undefined in my component.

Comment: @JarekOstrowski You are right - depending on which HttpClient / HttpModule you are using, .map(...) may be redundant. Change this .subscribe(data => this.users = data); to .subscribe(data => console.log(data)); and tell us what you see in console.

Comment: Yes, I receive data back inside the subscribe in the service. As soon as I try to get it from the component, it comes up undefined. Not sure why it's not pulling it in.

Comment: @JarekOstrowski The only difference I can see between the code above and my working code is the providers array. In my app.component.ts, providers array is empty, and the shared service is in the app.module.ts providers array. Otherwise, this implementation doesn't have issues.

Comment: @JarekOstrowski And if you are trying to console.log(usersService.users) from your app component, be aware that you may be printing users before it is fetched, and therefore undefined.

Comment: OMG, I didn't include it as a provider in app.module.ts. I may have been confused, thinking I had to put the provider in the component.ts instead of the module. Duh. Also, you were right about me trying to get usersService.users from the app component. Thanks for the simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Change your service as

```
 getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

and use **`subscribe()`** inside the component,

```
   this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data;
    });
```

Comment: sorry you should use this.users = data;

Comment: I'm trying to keep everything inside the service. Having to subscribe in every component I need the data is doing the same amount of work if I just get the GET request in each component. I was to call this.users without having to subscribe or run a function in every component I need the data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are returning within the subscription. Get is an async call Javascript doesn't know when it is going to return.

Quick Fix:
Get the prop directly After you make the REST call.

in your service:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users').subscribe(res => {
      this.users = res;
    });
```

in your component:

```
usersService.getUsers();
this.users = usersService.users;
```

Comment: Comes back undefined.

Comment: it will be undefined at the beginning, as it is an async operation. When your async call resolve, it will update your users objects with data.

Answer (score 0):

Your Service Class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
   }
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error || 'Server Error')
}
```

Your Component

```
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
providers: [ UsersService ]
})

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute, private usersService: UsersService) {
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(
        res => { this.users = res; },
        err => { console.log(err); }
    );
}
```

Make sure to import `{ Observable }`

Comment: Comes up undefined.

Comment: try catching the error, I updated my code to handleError.