# Angular return user info multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

I am new to programming and teaching myself and I searched a lot of sites but can't find the closest answer to a nagging problem that I have in my first app, with respect to some of the basic principles.

I have a tree in firestore containing some information about the user (name, bio, dob). They key for this user is the same as the key in firebase.User.

I subscribe to the current firebase.User through authstate, then use that uid to subscribe to my custom /users tree in firestore.

I have a service that returns the userObj but the only way I can get the currentUserObj is to include the wrapper around in the constructor on all of my pages (non-DRY). I wanted to create the service to set these objects and then have access throughout my app without adding in the boiler plate code every time. I have tried setting this through app.module in an effort to instantiate once but the variable objects aren't recognised in my other components.

///Boiler plate code that I am including in all of my pages

```
   this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
      if (user) {
        this.currentFirebaseUserObj = user
        this.userService.getUserObj(this.currentFirebaseUserObj.uid).valueChanges().subscribe(userObj => {
          this.currentUserObj = userObj as User;
        })
      }
    })
  };
```

/// the part that I have working through a service

```
  getUserObj(currentUserUid: string) {
    return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${currentUserUid}`)
  }
```

Is there a method to writing this once and then giving access to these objects throughout my app

Answer (score 1):

If you want to centralize the data into a service and access it from various parts of your application, then your subscription should take place inside your service. You can do this by subscribing to your observable inside the constructor of your service:

```
export class afAuth {

   userObj: User;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      // subscribe to getUserObj in here
   }

   getUserObj(currentUserUid: string) {
     return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${currentUserUid}`)
   }

}
```

Check out this implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48194096/5116121

On the other hand, if you do have to subscribe to it in your component, then once you have your userObj in your component, you can "set" it to a property of your service, which can later be accessible from other components.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that post does help. Ive followed the advice and subscribed in my component in the service, then made the injected service public in the component. I need to use  the objects that the service returns in the component and not the template. Currently i can access the userObjs. Any idea?
Edit. I have used this in the component, it means that I dont have all of that code, its just the format I was looking for to return the objects from the service
    this.currentUserObj = userService.currentUserObj
    this.currentFirebaseUserObj = userService.currentFirebaseUserObj

Comment: can access via this.afAuth, I can access it via userService.currentUserObj but just trying to load this before the rest of the code as I am having undefined errors

Comment: In that case you may need to carry the creation of your service into a higher level component, for instance by putting it inside the providers array of your app module.

Comment: I was looking at this and have [UserServiceProvider] in my app.module.ts. Is there a specific way to access the returns of this higher level component, over a service?

Comment: @Lee No, in that case, since your component is dependent of the data in your service, you can try to prevent loading the component until you have this data. If you are using selectors for instance, use <app-my component *ngIf="afAuth.userObj"> and that should create the component only when the data has arrived.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Cant get this to work so will leave it for now and come back to it. Tried placing the code in constructors and the other lifecycle hooks but still will come back undefined as the objects are required in components which call the service.